# Flipping images horizontally using 2D lists in python

Tags: python, image, nested-loops, nested-lists

```
def flip_horiz(pixels):

    height = len(pixels)
    width = len(pixels[0])
    image = create_blank_image(height,width)

    for r in range(height):
        for c in range(width):

            image[r][c] = pixels[r][((width-1)-c)]

    return image
```

I get an error that it is NONE TYPE

Comment: Can you paste the error?

Comment: We probably need the full error. Maybe `create_blank_image` is returning `None`?

Comment: def blank_image(height, width):
    
    image = create_uniform_image(height,width,[255,255,255])
    
    return image

Comment: Pixels is a 2D list of pixels

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    flipped = flip_horiz(pixels)
  File "C:\Users\Elihapc\Downloads\ps8image\ps8pr4.py", line 70, in flip_horiz
    image[r][c] = pixels[r][((width-1)-c)]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: For debugging, maybe try `print type(image)`, `print type(pixels)`. If none of those are `None`, try with `type(image[0])` and `type(pixels[0])`. See which of those is `None`.

Comment: @ElishaPuri You should include it in your post.

Comment: From the look of it, `create_blank_image` is returning `None`.